# Project Euler #35 - Circular Primes (Incorrect Result by 1)

Tags: python, algorithm, project, primes

I was trying to attempt the 35th problem of project euler ([click here](http://projecteuler.net/problem=35)). The problem goes something like:

> The number, 197, is called a circular prime because all rotations of the digits: 197, 971, and 719, are themselves prime.
>   There are thirteen such primes below 100: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, and 97.
>   How many circular primes are there below one million?

So I created a sieve with the first million numbers, to get all the primes under one million and used it to compare rotational results of primes numbers.

```
arr = []

for i in range(2, len(sieve)):
    if sieve[i]:
        sub_arr = retCircular(i)
        count = len(sub_arr)
        carry = 0
        for j in sub_arr:
            if sieve[j]:
                carry += 1
                sieve[j] = False
            else:
                break
        if carry == count:
            for j in sub_arr:
                arr.append(j)

print "Number of circular primes =", len(arr)
```

This program gave the number of circular primes under 1 million to be 54, whereas the actual answer is 55. Could someone help me with where I went wrong?

Note:

1. retCircular(n) is a user-defined function which returns all circular forms of the number in an array.
2. 'sieve' is an array of boolean values which contains True at all prime location indices and False at all composite location indices.

P/S, if anyone has a better approach to solve the problem, kindly let me know!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  In particular, we need the code to reproduce the problem.  We could also use your trace of logic & data -- which prime are you missing?

Comment: Add this before the loop: `print sieve[2]`. If the answer is `3`, you skipped the first prime.

Comment: Consider what will happen if your initial prime (before testing for circularity) contains any of the digits 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8.  Be careful with the single-digit primes 2 and 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use my consultant's ESP here: your retCircular method doesn't properly handle repeating patterns, which makes it miss *repunit* (string of 1's) primes.  In particular, retCircular(11) returns [11, 11], which makes your algorithm miss that number as a circular prime.  Here's my brute-force version of the method:

```
def retCircular(prime):
    prime_str = str(prime)
    family = [prime]
    for _ in range(len(prime_str)-1):
        prime_str = prime_str[1:] + prime_str[0]
        child = int(prime_str)
        if child == prime:
            break
        family.append(int(prime_str))
    return family
```

... and I get 55 primes with your main program:

```
Prime family: [2]
Prime family: [3]
Prime family: [5]
Prime family: [7]
Prime family: [11]
Prime family: [13, 31]
Prime family: [17, 71]
Prime family: [37, 73]
Prime family: [79, 97]
Prime family: [113, 131, 311]
Prime family: [197, 971, 719]
Prime family: [199, 991, 919]
Prime family: [337, 373, 733]
Prime family: [1193, 1931, 9311, 3119]
Prime family: [3779, 7793, 7937, 9377]
Prime family: [11939, 19391, 93911, 39119, 91193]
Prime family: [19937, 99371, 93719, 37199, 71993]
Prime family: [193939, 939391, 393919, 939193, 391939, 919393]
Prime family: [199933, 999331, 993319, 933199, 331999, 319993]
Number of circular primes = 55
```